# VB.NET: continue file upload on page navigation

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, vb.net, file-upload

Currently i have working scenario of uploading files on my website.
An ajax request sends the videos to HTTP Handler which successfully uploads them.

What I want to do is if user navigates from one page of application to another. The file uploading should not stop, instead it keep showing uploading files in header, and user can cancel them.

[image: sample]

As long as user is on application it should keep uploading files.

How is that possible in terms of architecture and coding. I will prefer not to use iframe/uploadify/telerik

This application is in VB.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid this is not possible in the web application because whenever user navigates to any other page, the last page will be destroyed and thus all background worker will be destroyed too.

Answer (score 0):

You could load your contentpages with jQuery eg.

```
function loadpage(page) {
   $("#maindiv").load(page);
}
```

so there is no need to reload the entire Page and your Uploads will not fail.